# Automatically generating a number of M2M relations in a model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models (simplified):

```
class InscriptionDate(models.Model):
    start_date = models.ForeignKey('Date', related_name='+')
    end_date = models.ForeignKey('Date', related_name='+')
    dates_in_range = models.ManyToManyField('Date', blank=True)

class Date(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    era = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ERA_CHOICES, default=BC)
```

I would like to have all the relevant M2M relationships generated for dates_in_range on save, after a start date and end date have been selected. The idea being that any date in the range could be queried and it would return the entries associated with that date.

The following is not correct, but this was the kind of approach I was thinking of taking:

```
 def save(self):
       start = self.start_date.year
       end = self.end_date.year
       for i in range(start, end):
          self.dates_in_range.add(year)
       super(InscriptionDate, self).save()
```

Is it possible to loop the add() for M2M relationships in this way? Can I generate and add a whole list of M2M relationships from input data in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Just remember to do this /after/ the `save()` call since you need  PK to add m2ms.

```
super(...).save()
self.dates_in_range.clear()
for year in range(start_year, end_year):
    date, created = Date.objects.get_or_create(year=year)
    self.dates_in_range.add(date)
```

Comment: So it should be something like this? 
`def add_dates_in_range(self):`
        `super(InscriptionDate, self).save()`
        `start_year = self.start_date.year`
        `end_year = self.end_year.year`
        `self.dates_in_range.clear()`
        `for year in range(start_year, end_year):`
            `date, created = Date.objects.get_or_create(year=year)`
            `self.dates_in_range.add(date)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the code you already have and implement it using a [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save)

e.g.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=InscriptionDate)
def add_dates_in_range(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    #assumes both years are in AD
    start_year = instance.start_date.year
    end_year = instance.end_date.year
    for year in range(start_year, end_year+1) #to include end_year
        date = Date.objects.get_or_create(year = year, era = 'AD')[0]
        instance.dates_in_range.add(date)
```

You could also implement dates_in_range as a method instead of a many-to-many relationship, but it really depends on how you plan to use your models.

e.g. (assumes you already have Date objects for all years between start_date and end_date, and all eras are AD)

```
class InscriptionDate(models.Model):
    start_date = models.ForeignKey('Date', related_name='+')
    end_date = models.ForeignKey('Date', related_name='+')
    def dates_in_range(self):
        return Date.objects.filter(year__lte = self.end_date.year, year__gte = self.start_date.year, era = 'AD')
```